# How to query for list of properties in a document

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I will be receiving flat documents that will have slightly different schemas.

For example:

```
{
   "FirstName": "Jim",
   "LastName: "Bob"
}
```

And another one, that would simply have:

```
{
   "FullName": "Jim Bob"
}
```

Is it possible to query the `Person` collection to retrieve the list of unique properties (not the values)?

```
[
   "FirstName",
   "LastName",
   "FullName"
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my [research](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-query-reference), it is not supported in cosmos db query syntax so far. You could refer to this similar [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/19737559-enumerate-all-properties-of-a-document) and adopt the suggestions from cosmos db team.

Also, I think you could get all the names of properties by below coding workaround.

1. Create and init a hashmap.
2. Query the documents and get the results array.
3. Loop the array and convert every json to map.
4. Push the elements into initial hashmap to make sure the list of properties is unique.

Comment: I was hoping that there was a built-in feature to accomplish this. Since there isn't, your answer seems to be the best way to accomplish this.

Comment: Hi Jay. Please try to refrain from adding "hope this helps" and other conversational items to your posts. Stack Overflow is intended to be a bit more like documentation than a chat room, and succinctness is valued! Thank you.